# Can't get inputs from html form

Tags: python, django

I want to create a webapp in Django that converts orders in pdf to excel file. To be more flexible i want to retrive text from pdf and pass it to form on HTML page to be editable. If everythig will be ok then i want to download excel file with data from inputs.
There is several inputs (depending on how much rows is in pdf with order) and i want to pass it all to my app. But below code dont work. Only result i have is token and value from button.

```
print(request.POST.keys())
print(request.POST['Submit'])
print(request.body)
```

```
<form action="extract_pdf" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <label class="input-group-text" for="inputGroupSelect01">Company ID</label>
                    </div>
                    <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01">
                        {% for item in company %}
                        <option value="a">{{item.1}}</option>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="company_name">Company Name</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="{{info.company_name}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="order_no">Order Number</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ord_no" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="{{info.order_number}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% for row in rows %}
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="item_nr">Jeeves Code</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="item" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="{{row.item}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="item_qty">Item Qty</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qty" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="{{row.qty}}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text" id="item_price">Item price</span>
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="price" aria-describedby="basic-addon3" value="{{row.price}}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Download" name="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Please help me find bug in my code :)

Comment: None of your input elements have `name` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to name your inputs. request.POST is a dictionary of key value pairs from the POST data, and if you do not provide names for the inputs there is no way for django to build that relationship and give you the data in your request.POST. Hope this helps!